# Multiple Drop Down in Form. How to manage in db tables

Tags: database, drop-down-menu, crud

I am creating an application for import export system.
In this application I have many forms.
Now let's talk about a single form.
I have 8 drop downs in this form.
To allow admin to add new values to each drop down i had to create table for each drop down so that it has all the values admin has defined.
I want to know is there an alter native of this problem because I see in the application there are nearly 35 different drop downs and I don't want to create 35 tables and forms then CRUD for every dropdown.
How can I manage it in an optimized and simple way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution to this problem with this methodoly

```
Table : dropdown
Columns : id , dropdown_name

Table : dropdown_fields
Columns : id , field_name , dropdown_id
```

This will i will create two cruds one for dropdown labels. In this admin will define crud title or name and nothing more.

In the second one admin will first select dropdown name from a dropdown coming from database table dropdown and then he will have a single field field_name to define.

And in the form where i have required these drop downs i can play with ids. Done it!